# numpy, matplotlib, and all newly added libraries keep showing error messages on import

Tags: python, windows, numpy, matplotlib, python-import

I have tried adding new libraries to my python installation such as numpy and matplotlib. However, after their installation I keep getting the error message.

---

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Issiah>python
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (
AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module
>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module
>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <mod
ule>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <modu
le>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

>>> exit()

C:\Users\Issiah>python -m pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\Issiah>python -m pip install numpy --force-reinstall
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\Issiah>
```

---

Here's another error from importing Pygame.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95,
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

It first started happening when I installed them using their respective setup.exe programs. Sometime later I used "pip install" and they all installed and imported without errors(I didn't actually use any of their library functions though). I then comeback the next day and upon import I started to get this error message.

Thanks for any advice.